# Confluent's Kafka and Zookeeper Docker Images don't play well on Mac OS X

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

Trying to run the Docker Images for Kafka & Zookeeper from `confluentinc` on my Mac. Unfortunately, the commands that the Confluent Docker Quickstart documentation provides utilize `net=host` which [does not work on Mac.](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/68).

Here are the original docker start-up scripts:

**Zookeeper**:

```
docker run -d \
    --net=host \
    --name=my-zookeeper \
    -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181 \
    -e ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME=2000 \
    -e ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT=2 \
    confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
```

**Kafka**:

```
docker run -d \
    --net=host \
    --name=my-kafka \
    -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=localhost:2181 \
    -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092 \
    -e KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \
    confluentinc/cp-kafka
```

So I tried removing `net=host` which turns into the following (with what I believe are the right port mappings):

**Zookeeper**:

```
docker run -d \
    --name=my-zookeeper \
    -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181 \
    -e ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME=2000 \
    -e ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT=2 \
    -p 2181:2181 \
    -p 2888:2888 \
    -p 3888:3888 \
    confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
```

**Kafka**:

```
docker run -d \
    --name=my-kafka \
    -e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=localhost:2181 \
    -e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092 \
    -e KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1 \
    -p 9092:9092 \
    confluentinc/cp-kafka
```

When I run it this way -- omitting `--net=host` from both, Kafka tries to connect to `localhost/127.0.0.1:2181` instead of simply `localhost:2181`. Not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Out of interest, have you tried https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-demo? This doesn't answer your question specifically, but I know for certain that it works on my Mac :) And thus maybe provides clues to your issues.

Comment: *So I tried removing net=host* ... [The quickstart says use Docker Machine](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/docs/quickstart.html). *If you’re running on Windows or macOS, you’ll need to use Docker Machine to start the Docker host*